# Access Issue with Newly Deployed Flask App on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm encountering an issue with accessing a newly deployed Flask application on the Google Cloud Platform. Here's the scenario:

I have an existing project on Google Cloud Platform with a default service hosting a PHP application in App Engine. Recently, I developed a Flask application locally and deployed it to the same project under a new service named "Python-flask-app".

However, when I attempt to access the service, I'm greeted with a "You don't have access" message.

below is the response in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () /favicon.ico:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status  app-name.appspot.com/:1 of 403 ()
```

Here's a snippet from my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python39
service: python-flask-app
```

my directory structure is like below:

```
Python-Testing (Folder)
  - templates (Folder)
  - app.yaml
  - client_secret.json
  - main.py
  - requirements.txt
```

Also, I got the below message when I used "gcloud app deploy":

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your deployment has succeeded, but promoting the new version to default failed. You may not have permissions to change traffic splits. Changing traffic splits requires the Owner, Editor, App Engine Admin, or App Engine Service Admin role. Please contact your project owner and use the `gcloud app services set-traffic --splits <version>=1` command to redirect traffic to your newly deployed version.

Original error: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

Please let me know how can I access it.

I tried creating a new project and deploy the same app. In the new project, I am able to click on the default service and can view the webpage.

Comment: Do you have IAP activated?

Comment: If you have IAP enabled, then the client must include the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer REPLACE_WITH_IDENTITY_TOKEN` for all requests. App Engine with IAP enabled supports web-based authorization. See this link: https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp-enterprise/docs/securing-app-engine If you do not require authorization, then disable IAP.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, I have IAP activated. I can see my email id listed in Role/Principal as a security reviewer. Do you mind telling me what particular details I should consider. 
Thank you

Comment: Did you review the error message? You need additional permissions to deploy an application. Request `App Engine Service Admin role` for the account that is deploying the app.

Comment: with IAP, the newly deployed service are secured by default. I you want to make it public, go to the IAP page and deactivate IAP on it. (add "allUsers" the role "IAP-secured Web App User")